# Calling a row on a data.table with multiple column key

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working with a data.table in r which has multiple columns as its key. For example:

```
 dt<-data.table(a=rep(1:6,each=4),b=rep(1:4,6),c=runif(24,0,4))
 setkey(dt,a,b)
```

This allows me to call the row in which the value of a=1 and the value of b=4 in the following way:

```
dt[.(1,4)]
#    a b        c
# 1: 1 4 3.178535
```

Which is great, but I want to use a variable to call a certain row, which is where I get into trouble:

```
rowKey <- c(1,4)
dt[rowKey]
#    a b        c
# 1: 1 1 3.871195
# 2: 1 4 3.178535
dt[.rowKey]
# Error in `[.data.table`(dt, .rowKey) : 
# .rowKey is not found in calling scope and it is not a column of type logical. When the first argument inside DT[...] is a single symbol, data.table looks for it in calling scope.
dt[.(rowKey)]
#    a b         c
# 1: 1 1 3.8711946
# 2: 1 2 0.8983114
# 3: 1 3 1.6121656
# 4: 1 4 3.1785354
# 5: 4 1 3.1755705
# 6: 4 2 1.3172628
# 7: 4 3 1.4005534
# 8: 4 4 0.4579921
```

Non of these give me the desired row. How can I use the variable rowKey to call this single row in my data table?

Comment: Fyi, you should be using integers to match integers. See `dt[.(1,4), verbose=TRUE]` vs `dt[.(1L,4L), verbose=TRUE]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rowKey <- list(1,4)

dt[rowKey]

#   a b         c
#1: 1 4 0.4778884
```

---

`.(1,4)` means `list(1,4)`. If you want the same, use the same for rowKey.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap `rowKey` in `as.list`:

```
> dt[as.list(rowKey)]
   a b        c
1: 1 4 1.619764
```

(or make a list instead of a vector as @AndreElrico showed)